# How to share a dll in a network directory not the same as the application directory

Tags: vb.net, networking, dll, shared, drive

I'll admit up front that I'm still learning good methods of deployment and that I don't have a size 12 brain to accomplish the following task. Now with that being said...
We have around 8 exe's that exist on a network drive that reference a dll that is in the same share/folder.  We'd like to have a common network share in a different location that would contain this dll and any future dll's that we create so we'd have only one place to make changes (presuming the apps do not need to be recompiled).  I've not found a satisfactory answer for why a dll should not be shared on a network so I'm wondering what the best practice would be for doing this.  If this is something that is acceptable and routinely done then what steps are necessary to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this shared DLL has any chance of being updated during a future release, what you have now, a local copy stored against each application, is far better.

You say your stated objective is to be able to make one change to the DLL and have all apps update.  I've heard the positive side of this case made before.

"We get to roll out improvements to all our apps"

Which, seen from a half-empty glass is :-

"We get to introduce common bugs to all our apps".

Even at eight projects, imagine what your launches will be like.

"Er, hello QA.  Can you test this one new app? (plus the seven others that we've done nothing to but might be broken as a result)".

Libraries should only be shared if they are mature and unlikely to change.  Sorry to be so up-front about it, but I've faced a zealot who absolutely believed as you do.   It was only when our bottom-line (predictably) nose-dived that my concerns were listened to.  Dragons ahead.  Be warned!

Comment: Paul, thanks for your input that is the type of answer I was looking for.  The stakeholders don't care where the programs are ran from but my boss is looking for a better way of updating a dll where so many apps are relying on it.  What we have now is a local copy on the network share where the exe's reside, but would adding the dll to the GAC be easier to manage?  If so, how would an update to a dll be pushed to the pc's that use it?  I'm somewhat new to this sort of thing so be blunt, don't hold back.  If there's a solid way to do this then I'd want to know about it.  Again, thanks.

Comment: I should add that we're a small shop so any testing/implementing/changing is done by myself or my boss (yep, small IT = big headaches).

Comment: Don't know if the GAC helps you.  Think it's machine-specific, but has all the same problems as any shared approach.

Now, it sounds as if you've got a number of client PCs that may rely on this DLL.  That is a lot different than my background, which is mostly public facing web apps.  None of my programs ever really exist on the clients machine in anything other than markup or Javascript form.

Is this a Windows app installed on lots of different machines?

Comment: No, they're compile stand-alone's residing on a network share drive.  The dll they rely on is in the same folder, but won't be or hasn't been changed very much.  I had to make a change to the dll to fix an issue with our picklists and am in the process of testing the remaining exe's (no sandbox to play in)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to finalize this question.  The solution we are going with is if there is a need to modify the dll to support an exe then we'll place them both in its own folder so Paul's suggestion was about right.